# What are the options to store some data values to be accessed on the server side if we're not using a Database?

Tags: node.js, database, amazon-web-services, storage, server-side

We're running a server and need to store some specific data values (that will be used by the server continuously) . This data is going to be aprox 5-10 key-value pairs. We're not using a Database on the back-end. What are the best possible solutions to store these data values, considering the fact that, If I wish to change the values for the data points, I should be able to do it anytime without creating any disturbance to the server (once updated, the server will use the updated values ).

We're open to use any centralized data-storage options (not a full blown DB) that can be used to store extremely limited data values and is inexpensive.

Comment: try redis, or just simple have a SQLite db (you dont need to install any software), or keep it in JSON file.

Comment: Hey @shyammakwana.me Thanks for your response. I'll check on them once.

Comment: You could also check out the Systems Manager Parameter Store depending on the amount of requests you have. If you require little throughput, that can even be free.

Comment: Hey @Maurice Thanks for your suggestion. We're already using the Param store for a specific job. Sounds good for this purpose as well. Thanks. :)

Comment: If you do not want to use a traditional db, consider https://aws.amazon.com/athena/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc

Comment: Thanks @smac2020 but I guess Athena is going to be really expensive for this use case right?